# Extract rows from a CSV file that contain any of the values from another CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, csv

I have been struggling with this particular issue for some time:

I have one `output.csv` file that looks like this:

[image]

And another `07.csv` file that looks like this:

[image]

What I would like to do is take the values from column mmsi in output.csv file and check if any of those values are in any of the rows in 07.csv and extract those rows in a new results072.csv file.
So far this is my code,but it does a very strange thing: it somehow makes this new file as big as the 07.csv and has many more appearances of the lines that contain the values.
I would really appreciate some feedback! Thank you in advance!

```
import csv
with open('output.csv') as hashes:
    hashes = csv.reader(hashes,delimiter = ',')
    hashes = set(col[1] for col in hashes)
    hashi= list(hashes)

with open('07.csv') as input_file, open('result072.csv', 'w') as output_file: 
    reader = csv.reader(input_file,delimiter = ',')
    writer = csv.writer(output_file,delimiter = ',')

for row in reader:
    if any(item in row for item in hashi):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Your python code looks quite unformatted - could you please check the formatting again?

Comment: I reformatted it - waiting in the approval queue

Comment: I can't test your code because I can't load images into my text editor. But it looks like none of the mmsi values of the first CSV are repeated in the second CSV, so your program should produce no output. Perhaps you should give us some better sample input, and in text form so we can actually use it.

Comment: @PM 2Ring These are two lines in the 07.csv :
time                   sog                                   y                       x                    mmsi
1420598820 0.10000000149011612 54.635935 -8.439985 250000527
1420664100 2.9000000953674316 54.44025 11.382183333333   211312240

And these two are from output.csv
imo           mmsi                name            flag               type
9107617 211312240 GLAUBE          DE             Fishing
9040675 250000527 F/V RACHEL   IE  Fishing Vessel

Sorry for bad formatting I am still learning how to get around here. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to get all the mmsi values from the output.csv file and step through the 07.csv, comparing each entry with all the mmsi values. If it matches, write the line to a new file.

I am not very good with the `any` function, so I tried by hand.

```
import csv

with open('output.csv') as hashes:
    csv_data = csv.reader(hashes, delimiter = ',')
    mmsi_set = set(col[1] for col in csv_data)
    mmsi_list = list(hashes)


with open('07.csv') as input_file, open('result072.csv', 'w') as output_file: 
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter = ',')
    writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter = ',')

    for row in reader:
        for mmsi in mmsi_list:
            if mmsi == row[4]:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

The above code should write any line of 07.csv to the new file result072.csv where the mmsi from output.csv matches the mmsi of 07.csv

Comment: It seems to be doing the same thing my code does-somehow in the result072.csv file I get more than I should (so for example if there was 9 lines having 235067469 it somehow appears that there are 101 lines in the result072.csv which is very strange and I have no idea why..

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment, I still had my old result072.csv
I have tried to run this, but the result072.csv seems to be empty even though,when manually checked there should be some matches. What can it be? Thank you so much for the help, it is for my thesis! :)

Comment: If you could provide some test data, I would be able to check where the issue is hiding.

Comment: Hey, thanks I managed to solve it, it was not the code that was the issue..The app I am using to open .csv files did not show me more than 65535, which I did not consider is a limit..